# Is it possible to send ngrok live video stream directly to visual studio for object detection using openCV librabries?

Tags: esp32, ngrok

I am planning to design an ESP32CAM-based traffic detection for specific vehicle. Is it possible to send ngrok live video stream directly to visual studio for object detection using  openCV libraries?